# Neat proof for Measure Theory question (preferably with minimal usage of simple functions)

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ be a measurable function. Define the map $\lambda:\mathcal{M}\to[0,\infty]$, $\lambda(E)=\int_X \chi_E\ f d\mu$, where $\chi_E$ denotes the characteristic function of $E$.

Show that for any measurable function $g:X\to[0,\infty]$, one has $\int_X gd\lambda=\int_X gf d\mu$ in $[0,\infty]$.

Is there any neat way to prove the above? I tried using the definition (sup of simple functions) and it got quite messy.

Thanks for any help.

(We may use the fact that $\lambda$ is a measure, and it is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$).

Comment: The equality you want holds for characteristic functions by definition. By linearity, it holds for simple functions. For any $g\geq 0$, use monotone convergence theorem [using the fact that $\lambda$ is a positive measure]

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to avoid simple functions? After all, they are used to define the integral, so it seems reasonable to use them.

Comment: A recurring pattern for these sorts of problems is as @PrahladVaidyanathan pointed out: First characteristic functions, then simple functions (linearity), then measurable functions (using a relevant convergence theorem). You will see this again and again in measure theory. And again.

Comment: @copper.hat And again

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thanks, I get the first two parts. Could you elaborate a bit on the monotone convergence part? Thanks

Comment: Also, do we only consider simple functions for g? Do we need to consider simple functions for f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\geq 0$, there is a sequence $(s_n)$ of non-negative simple functions such that $s_n\nearrow g$. Since $\lambda$ is a positive measure,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X s_n d\lambda = \int_X gd\lambda
$$
and since $s_nf \nearrow gf$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X s_nf d\mu = \int_X gfd\mu
$$
Now use the fact the corresponding terms in the limit are equal.